# onkeypress doenst work properly on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hey i'm using React and i can't figure out why my onKeyPress doesn't work .

I use the onKeyPress and i defined the function but nothing changes.

This is my code. Please check it out

```html
<div className ="">
   <input 
      onClick = {this.onSubmitSignIn}
      className ="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib" 
      type="submit" 
      value="Register"
      onKeyPress = {this.keyPressed} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onKeyPress` event is assigned on a non-typeable element ie. submit button. So, you cannot expect it to work as you think. User will not press the key when in the submit button active/click.

Instead you may assign `onKeyPress` event on `document` and then bind the action.

If you use hook, then it will be like:

```
const onKeyPress = event => {
  console.log(event)
}
useEffect(() => 
  document.addEventListener('keypress', e => onKeyPress(e))
  return () => { // clean up
   document.removeListener('keypress', onKeyPress)
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i do it in react

Comment: The same way you bound in the  button. Just you need to bind it on document or  closure wrapper on which  user may be active instead.

Comment: can you help me more    i've done this <document.getElementById('on').addEventListener('keyPress',event=>{
          console.log('a')
         })  />         and i got the error

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," and it's  show something on return

Comment: I think you should be able to fix that error. check code properly for the mistake.

Comment: acctually i've put this on the top of my class is it wrong??

Comment: yes. if you're using classs then you can use componentDidMount hook instead of useEffect.

Comment: well can i have your id on twitter to send you all of my code because i get confused

Answer (score 0):

I read that the [keypress event is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event).

The click event responds to Enter key as well, so I suggest you use the [`mouseUp` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) to handle mouse clicks separately, and use [`keyUp` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) to handle the Enter key.

`if (event.key === "Enter")` in the code below checks if the key pressed is Enter key.

```js
keyUp = (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // The function you want to call
  }
};

render() {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <input
        onMouseUp={this.onSubmitSignIn}
        className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
        type="submit"
        value="Register"
        onKeyUp={this.keyUp}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue. See my answer.

Comment: no i don't want the value i want to take action . but right now , i'm trying to run the program at least

Comment: My bad, didn't read it well. What do you want to do with `onKeyPress`?

Comment: if it was enter key run another function

Comment: Sorry, I don't know then